# Kendo UI fixed width column size get increase on resizeing the grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I set first column with fixed width '31px', But when all column make small size and resize the grid by resizeing the container, the first column with get increase. In feddle example if you make Title and Age column size small as in [Screen shot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/943996/2fa942f5338b9402a3e0328df6a86636) and then resize you will see the first column width increase.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
data: createRandomData(50),
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            FirstName: { type: "string" },
            LastName: { type: "string" },
            City: { type: "string" },
            Title: { type: "string" },
            Age: { type: "number" }
        }
    }
},
pageSize: 10
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    height: 450,
    sortable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columnResize : saveWidthOfColumns,
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    columns: JSON.parse('[{"title":"FirstName","width":"31px"},{"title":"Title","width":null},{"title":"Age","width":null}]')
});
});
function saveWidthOfColumns(event) {
if (event.column.field == null) {
    $("#grid colgroup").each(function() {
        $(this).find(":nth-child(1)").css("width", "31px");
    });
}
} 
$(window).resize(function() {
resizeGrid();
});
function resizeGrid() {
var newWidth = $('body').innerWidth() - 20;
var oldWidth = $(".k-grid-content table").width() - 20;
if(oldWidth < newWidth)
{
    $(".k-grid-content").css("padding-right", "18px");
    $(".k-grid-content table").css("width",newWidth + "px");
    $(".k-grid-header-wrap table").css("width",newWidth + "px");
}
```

}

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HAMEh/328/)

Comment: Please note, that the question **have to** contain **a question** (e.g., at the end). This way you sharpen your question and make it easier to answer.

Comment: Why don't use the .resize widget method instead of doing it manually? Here is an example of resize when window change http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/resize-grid-when-the-window-is-resized

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but try removing the width style from your container div and the grid will fill and resize appropriately.

Comment: I want to make first column width always '31px', But the problem is that when I title and Age column set with minimum width, then resize the container, the first column width get change I want it same as before resize. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAMEh/329/)